# change the query parameter of android view model on the basis of preference change listener

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using architecture component in my application. I have used paging but I have a problem that how to re-query the db if parameter gets changed on the basis of preferences. Because view model is setup in oncreate method and it we call a query on Dao interface inside view model constructor.

I tried to recreate the view model inside onPreferenceChangeLitener but its not working.

My main activity is as-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    RecyclerView rvDisplayMovie;
    MovieAdapter mAdapter;

    MainActivityViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvDisplayMovie = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_display_movies);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rvDisplayMovie.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MovieAdapter();

        rvDisplayMovie.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        MainViewModelFactory factory = InjectorUtils.provideMainViewModelFactory(this);

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

        mViewModel.getMovies().observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<MovieEntry>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<MovieEntry> movieEntries) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Movie list changed"+movieEntries.size());
                mAdapter.submitList(movieEntries);
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_settings,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        mViewModel.triggerPrefsChenged(this);
    }
}
```

and view model is-

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivityViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

    private PopularMovieRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<PagedList<MovieEntry>> mMovies;

    public MainActivityViewModel(PopularMovieRepository repository, int movieType){
        mRepository = repository;
        mMovies = mRepository.getMoviesList(movieType);
    }

    public  LiveData<PagedList<MovieEntry>> getMovies() {
        return mMovies;
    }

    public void triggerPrefsChenged(Context context){
        int movieType = PreferenceUtils.getMovieType(context);
        mRepository.initializeData(movieType);
    }
}
```

triggerPrefsChenged method downloads new data and insert it in to database

Comment: Could you please share the relevant code?

Comment: I have added relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem with your approach is that your `mMovies` is hardcoded for the initial `movieType` (the one you pass in `MainActivityViewModel`). You should modify your `mMovies` usage so that it could react to `movieType` changes.

A good way to do this is to create an additional `LiveData` object that listens to `movieType` changes and then triggers `mRepository.getMoviesList(movieType)` call with the new type using `Transformations.switchMap`. So, your ViewModel could be as follows:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivityViewModel.class.getSimpleName();
    private PopularMovieRepository mRepository;
    private final MutableLiveData<Integer> mMovieTypeLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
    private final LiveData<PagedList<MovieEntry>> mMovies;

    public MainActivityViewModel(PopularMovieRepository repository, int movieType){
        mRepository = repository;
        mMovies = Transformations.switchMap(movieTypeLive, (movieType) -> {
            return mRepository.getMoviesList(movieType);
        });
        //set the initial value
        mMovieTypeLiveData.setValue(movieType);
    }

    public LiveData<PagedList<MovieEntry>> getMovies() {
        return mMovies;
    }

    public void triggerPrefsChenged(Context context){
        int movieType = PreferenceUtils.getMovieType(context);
        //mRepository.initializeData(movieType);
        mMovieTypeLiveData.setValue(movieType);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kanchan a pleasure